# C# Importing multiple txt files data getting jumbled

Tags: c#, io

I have written a piece of code to read the contents of many text files from a certain directory.

I am aware I have posted incomplete code so the help I will receive is limited, however I ask this question so I can learn what I'm doing wrong with my code, not so I can get an easy copy and paste solution.

All of the text files I wish to get data from are setup exactly the same. I then export that data to a separate text file "ImportedUsers.txt" which lists all of the users along with their First Name, Last Name, Full Name, Company and Notes. At the moment, the first file is imported correctly, however for any further files, the data is getting mixed up, where if the Full Name is left blank, the Company then ends up in the "Notes" field.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does it work out when you move your variable definition

```
int numComma = 0;
```

inside the loop:

```
for (int intFileNameNumber = 0; intFileNameNumber < importFileFormat.Length; intFileNameNumber++)
```

so you can count number of commas separately for each file.

I would suggest separating the logic of importing and exporting files, it looks really hard to read :)

Comment: That solves the issue! I can't believe it was that small of an issue...didn't even think of that. THANK YOU!